# React Navigation (and React Native) - How to get a routeur into a modal to get more views?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I got this code:

```
<Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName='SendButton'
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        animation: 'none',
        contentStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name='SendButton' component={SendButton} />
      </Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'fullScreenModal', animation: 'slide_from_bottom' }}>
        <Stack.Screen name='ItemSelection' component={ItemSelection} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ItemAmount' component={ItemAmount} />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

It's works, but when I want open `ItemAmount` it's open a new Modal where I would like stay in this first Modal and display the next View.

I just look on React Navigation documentation, did have chat with GPT, but I got nothing.

I tried `navigation.navigate` and `navigation.push` into my ItemSelection component to go on ItemAmount, but no change.